# Provided a relative flux v/s wavelength plot, how can I calculate the radial velocity of an exoplanet?

Tags: exoplanet, spectra, radial-velocity

I imagine the relativistic version of the Doppler effect would be appropriate but I'm not entirely sure since flux is a measure of intensity. Alternatively, where could I find redshift data for exoplanets? I can only get my hands on Echelle grating spectra which is admittedly a little difficult to understand. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Question is confusing. What exactly is the data you have? The question about obtaining RV data is an entirely separate question to that in the title.